# Spark Join Single Dataframe to a Collection of Dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I'm struggling to figure out an elegant solution to join a single dataframe to a separate sequence of 1 to N related dataframes. Initial attempt:

```
  val sources = program.attributes.map(attr => {
    spark.read
      .option("header", value = true)
      .schema(program.GetSchema(attr))
      .csv(s"${program.programRawHdfsDirectory}/${attr.sourceFile}")
  })
  val rawDf: DataFrame = sources.reduce((df1, df2) => df1.join(df2, program.dimensionFields, "full"))

  // Full of fail:
  val fullDf: DataFrame = program.dimensions.filter(d => d.hierarchy != "RAW").reduceLeft((d1, _) => {
    val hierarchy = spark.read.parquet(d1.hierarchyLocation).where(d1.hierarchyFilter)
    rawDf.join(hierarchy, d1.hierarchyJoin)
  })

  fullDf.selectExpr(program.outputFields:_*).write.parquet(program.programEtlHdfsDirectory)
```

The reduceLeft idea doesn't work because I'm iterating through a collection of configuration objects (the dimensions property), but what I want returned from each iteration is a dataframe. The error is a type mismatch, which is not surprising.

The core of the problem is that I have 1 to N "dimension" objects that define how to load an existing hierarchy table and also how to join that table to my "raw" dataframe I created earlier.

Any idea how I might create these joins without some sort of horrible hack?

**UPDATE:**

I wonder is this might work? I have a common field name in each hierarchy dataframe that I'm joining to. If I renamed this common field to match the corresponding column in my "raw" dataframe, could I execute the joins in a fold without explicitly calling out the columns? Will Spark just default to the matching names?

```
  val rawDf = sources.reduce((df1, df2) => df1.join(df2, program.dimensionFields, "full"))

  val hierarchies = program.dimensions.map(dim => {
    spark.read.parquet(dim.hierarchyLocation).where(dim.hierarchyFilter).withColumnRenamed("parent_hier_cd", dim.columnName)
  })
  val fullDf = hierarchies.foldLeft(rawDf) { (df1, df2) => df1.join(df2) }
```

**UPDATE 2**

No, that does not work. Spark attempts a cross join.

Comment: FoldLeft is your friend :)

Comment: See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48893002/manipulating-a-dataframe-within-a-spark-udf/48893081#48893081 Code at end of answer. Btw to others, this is not a dupe, but very similar

Comment: Thank you - that was actually my first approach. The trouble is that the information about what column or columns are used in each join are contained within the dimension object.

Comment: Ok, see it. Maybe create List of DataFeames, zip with join Column List and foldLeft this?

Comment: Yeah, that is worth pursuing, especially if the idea in my UPDATE doesn't pan out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my purposes, I simply needed to return a tuple when generating the collection of hierarchies:

```
  val hierarchies = program.dimensions.map(dim => {
    val hierarchy = spark.read.parquet(dim.hierarchyLocation).where(dim.hierarchyFilter).alias(dim.hierarchy.toLowerCase)
    (dim, hierarchy)
  })
```

Then when I fold them into `rawDf`, I have the metadata I need to construct the joins.