# passing the Spark ParserInterface in the udf

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a data frame that has user queries as one of the columns. I have a function that will be deriving the important columns in these queries and returning the columns as a set of string. This set of String will be a new column for my data frame. For that purpose I need the spark ParserInterface as an argument to the udf fnction.

```
  def gettingColumns(sqlParser: ParserInterface, querySt: String, tablename: String, dbName: String): Set[String] = {


    val logicalPlan = sqlParser.parsePlan(querySt)

    Set[String]()

/**will implement the parsing logic later**/
}
val udfForColumns = udf(gettingColumns _)

    val sqlParser: ParserInterface = sparkSession.sessionState.sqlParser

df.withColumn("mainColumns", udfForColumns(typedLit(sqlParser), $"query", $"table_name", $"database_name"))
```

expected

```
df:
-------------------------------------------
|query | table_name| db_name| mainColumns|
------------------------------------------
|q1    | t1.       | d1     | Set[String]()|
---------------------------------------------
```

got

```
User class threw exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser@18c138b7
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser@18c138b7
```

Answer (score 1):

A UDF is meant to receive columns as parameters as you noticed already.

But `lit(...)` only support types that make sense in a column. The `sqlParser` is not a simple value (like a string, int...) that can be in a column.

Instead, the general approach would be to create a UDF that doesn't need the `sqlParser`:

```scala
val sqlParser = ???
val udfForColumns = udf((x, y, z) => gettingColumns(sqlParser, x, y, z))
```

*Note that I don't know enough Spark and I have a doubt that it's even possible to access the parser (spark session) from a UDF in the 1st place. You'll have to try.*

EDIT: [spark read doesn't work inside Scala UDF function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677747/spark-read-doesnt-work-inside-scala-udf-function) tends to indicate this won't be possible this way.